# My phone is giving inaccurate readings of battery level

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery, sensors, huawei-u8160

I have a Huawei u8160 running Cyanogenmod 7.2 .

my phone is giving inaccurate readings of the battery charge level (e.g one day morning it was 33 that day evening it became 34 without touching the phone)

is that an indicator of malfunctioning battery,or the sensor is reporting false readings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very uncommon for Cyanogen to have some problem with battery status reading. Things you can try:

- Turn off the phone and take off the battery for a while;
- Let the battery fully drain and then reset the battery calibration on clockwork recovery;
- Try an app like [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1024867).

**Note:** I'm not sure why, but when I changed my battery visualization to a percentage view instead of the default (in the Cyanogen configuratons), the battery lectures of my smartphone started to give me wrong readings. When I switched back, it got back to normal *after a fully recharging*.